# Drupal views strip HTML - Paragraphs sticking together

Tags: drupal, view, strip-tags

I'm using Drupal 6 and Views 2 to display titles and a summary of the body of some content. I wanted to strip out the HTML so that tables and images etc don't display in the node summary. It is preferable in this situation to trim the body rather than use the 'teaser'.

However, when paragraph and line break HTML is removed, the sentences get 'stuck together' - for example:

This is a paragraph. It has two sentences.
This is a second paragraph.

Becomes...

This is a paragraph. It has two sentences.This is a second paragraph.

There is no space after the second period. How can I strip out the HTML but somehow insert spaces in these situations (or achieve a similar result)?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the field under 'Fields header' eg node:body body and there you will find 'strip HTML' right below trim option. Check that option and you will get desired result.

Comment: I'm currently using that - but it is producing the undesirable effect I describe in my question: squashing paragraphs and line-breaks together without a space.